# Porting struct.unpack from python 2.7 to 3

Tags: python

The following code works fine in python 2.7:

```
def GetMaxNoise(data, max_noise):
    for byte in data:
        noise = ComputeNoise(struct.unpack('=B',byte)[0])
        if max_noise < noise:
            max_noise = noise
    return max_noise
```

where data is a string holding binary data (taken from a network packet).

I'm trying to port it to Python 3 and I get this:

> File "Desktop/Test.py", line 2374, in GetMaxNoise
>
> noise = ComputeNoise(struct.unpack('=B',byte)[0])
>
> TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface

How can I convert "data" to the appropriate type needed by unpack()?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the `data` variable is a *string of bytes* that you got from a binary file on a network packet, it it not processed the same in Python2 and Python3.

In Python2, it is a string. When you iterate its values, you get single byte strings, that you convert to int with `struct.unpack('=B')[0]`

In Python3, it is a `bytes` object. When you iterate its values, you directly get integers! So you should directly use:

```
def GetMaxNoise(data, max_noise):
    for byte in data:
        noise = ComputeNoise(byte)  # byte is already the int value of the byte...
        if max_noise < noise:
            max_noise = noise
    return max_noise
```

Comment: In this case it's the better solution, to just cut out the `unpack`. Yours answer is better :)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of the struct module https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html I see that the unpack method expects it's second argument to implement Buffer Protocol, so it generally expects `bytes`.

Your `data` object seems to be of the type `bytes` as it's read from somewhere. When you iterate over it with the `for` loop, you end up with `byte` variable being single `int` values.

I don't know what your code is supposed to do and how, but maybe change the way you iterate over your `data` object to handle not `int`s but `bytes` of `length == 1`?

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    byte = data[i:i+1]
    print(byte)
```

Comment: Hmm, it works, but you are doing that all only to keep the individual bytes in `bytes` format to be able to convert them later to integers, when directly iterating a `bytes` gives the same integer. Looks pretty much like *one step forth and the latter back*