# Python 2 to Python 3 Struct Pack Issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, struct

I'm trying to get the following code to work in Python 3. It is fine in Python 2. I have changed the `xrange`s to `range`, but there is a problem with this line: `data = ''.join(struct.pack('f', samp) for samp in tone)`:

`sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found.`

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33960728/3042018) but couldn't work out how to apply it to my situation. Any help much appreciated.

```
import math
import struct
import pyaudio

def play_tone(frequency, amplitude, duration, fs, stream):
    N = int(fs / frequency)
    T = int(frequency * duration)  # repeat for T cycles
    dt = 1.0 / fs
    # 1 cycle
    tone = (amplitude * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * n * dt)
            for n in xrange(N))
    # todo: get the format from the stream; this assumes Float32
    data = ''.join(struct.pack('f', samp) for samp in tone)
    for n in xrange(T):
        stream.write(data)

fs = 48000
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
    channels=1,
    rate=fs,
    output=True)

# play the C major scale
scale = [130.8, 146.8, 164.8, 174.6, 195.0, 220.0, 246.9, 261.6]
for tone in scale:
    play_tone(tone, 0.5, 0.75, fs, stream)

# up an octave
for tone in scale[1:]:
    play_tone(2*tone, 0.5, 0.75, fs, stream)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: *"there is a problem"* - would you care to share with us what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the empty string you're joining on is in fact a `str` instance (a Unicode string), but the values you're joining together (that you get from `struct.pack`) are `bytes` instances. Python 3 doesn't let you mix the different string types together like that.

Change the `''` to `b''` and it should work: `data = b''.join(struct.pack('f', samp) for samp in tone)`